# first derivative upper limit of Linear inhomogeneous system ODE response function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let's have the following system $(2\times2)$ of linear in-homogeneous ODE:

$$x'_1(t) = A_{11} ~ x_1(t) + A_{12} ~ x_2(t) + B_1~g(t)$$

$$x'_2(t) = A_{21} ~ x_1(t) + A_{22}~ x_2(t) + B_2~g(t) $$

then we define response function $y(t)$ as:

$$y(t) = C_0 ~ g(t) + C_1 ~ x_1(t) + C_2 ~ x_2(t)$$

where $~C_0,~C_1~$ and $~C_2~$ are positive real constants.

Parameters $(A_{ij},$ and $B_i)$ satisfy to the globally non-negative real solutions $~x_1(t)\ge 0,~~ x_2(t) \ge 0~,$ for initial conditions $~x_1(0) = x_{1}^0{} \ge0~$ and $~x_2(0) = x_{2}^{0} \ge 0~.$

**Question** is: Is possible to find any good upper limit $~y'_\text{max}~$ estimation of response function first derivative $~|y'(t)| \le y'_\text{max}~,$ if we know that $~|g'(t)| \le g'_\text{max}~$ and $~g_\text{max} \ge g(t) \ge 0~.$

Upper limit $~y'_\text{max}~$ should depends only on ODE parameters $~(A_{ij}, B_i)~, $response constants $~C_0, ~C_1,~C_2~$ and function $~g(t)~$ upper limit $~g_\text{max}~$ (see analytical solution for special case $A_{ij} = 0$) together with $~|g'(t)|~$ upper limit $~g'_\text{max}~$.

The main motivation of this problem is the fact, that we are looking for any suitable analytical limit conditions for response function $~y(t)~$ and its first derivative $~y'(t)~$ to be able identify spurious errors at $~y(t)~$ measured signals.

Comment: sorry for poor formatting  ...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For mathematical expression, use MathJax formatting. See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference